# Symfony form submit button not working

Tags: symfony, controller, twig, submit

I'm trying to submit a form which is supposed to deactivate several documents. When hitting the "Submit" button nothing happens.
Here is my twig file:

```
{% block content %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form(form.documentlist) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<p>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-multiselect.js') }}"></script>
<script>

makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ form.vars.name }}_documentlist', 'Select Document');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#{{ form.vars.name }}_documentlist').change(function() {
    var docId = $('#{{ form.vars.name }}_documentlist').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'id': docId},
    });
  });
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

and my Controller function:

```
  /**
  * @Route("/document/bulkdeactivate", name="documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function bulkDeactivateAction(Request $request) {

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $selected_documents = $request->request->all();

      $form = $this->createForm(DocumentDeactivationType::class);
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
        foreach($selected_documents as $document) {
        $documentR = json_decode(json_encode($document), true);
        dump($documentR);
        for($i=0; $i<count($documentR); $i++){
          $doc = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($documentR[$i]);
          dump($doc);
          $document->setActive(false);
          $em->persist($document);
          $em->flush();
        }
      }

            $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'The document has been deactivated!'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
            }

          return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Panels:ActivationPanel.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
          ));
}
```

I looked in the console while hitting "Submit" and it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null
at window.onload (bulkdeactivate:257)
```

which is the line that renders the twig template. I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem, just wanted to let you know as much as I know!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably somewhere in javascript you're trying to set href attribute on element that doesn't exist. I see `href` attribute in <button> but <button> tag doesn't have such attribute, so probably when that button is clicked you get `href` attribute of it in javascript and use it somewhere

Comment: I removed the href from my button but it didn't help unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: your submit button needs to be inside the form. Before the `{{ form_end(form) }}`

Comment: @Elyass I changed it but it still doesn't work. maybe it's a logic problem in my controller?

Comment: If submit is inside form now and still nothing happens maybe there is javascript that prevents form submition

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that, too @ArtOsi, but I don't know where? do you see anything? I posted all the javascript from that file. I only have the "makeMultiselectDropdown" and the ajax function and I think, the ajax function might be the problem, but since I'm very new to javascript I can't really see yet, where the mistake might be..

Comment: Javascript could be in another file as well. Check which scripts are included in page