# Symfony form not valid and not submittable

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

When trying to submit my form, it is not working. The button is not doing anything at all. So I tried to dump something withing my:

```
if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted())
```

And realized that it's not even entering the if statement, so I assume that there is something wrong with my form. But I can't yet figure out what it would be, so I would be glad if anyone could help me!

```
 /**
  * @Route("/document/bulkdeactivate", name="documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function bulkDeactivateAction(Request $request) {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $selected_documents = $request->request->all();
      $form = $this->createForm(DocumentDeactivationType::class);
      $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
          foreach($selected_documents as $document) {
          $documentR = json_decode(json_encode($document), true);
          dump($documentR);
            for($i=0; $i<count($documentR); $i++){
              $doc = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($documentR[$i]);
              dump($doc);
              $doc->setActive(false);
              $em->persist($doc);
              $em->flush();
            }
          }
          $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'The document has been deactivated!'
          );
          return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
        }
        return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Panels:ActivationPanel.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
  }
```

my Form Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
      'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
      'choice_label' => 'name',
      'required' => false,
      'multiple' => true,
      'expanded' => false,
      'placeholder' => "Select Documents",
      'label' => 'label.document_list',
        ))

->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
  'label' => 'Submit',
  'attr' => array(
      'class' => 'btn btn btn-default',
  ),
  ));
  }
```

And the form part of my twig template:

```
     {% block content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form(form.documentlist) }}
 {{ form(form.submit) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {% endblock content %}
```

There must be some issues with the form, do you have any advice for my?

Comment: Well the errors should be displayed in your template. Check out the form debug panel and this question to display manually your form errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208992/symfony2-invalid-form-without-errors/26504382#26504382

Comment: I already used the form getErrors() method, and the result is an empty array.. 
FormErrorIterator {#1586 ▼
  -form: Form {#1570 ▶}
  -errors: []
}

Comment: Your save submit is not linked to the form thus should not be recognized by Symfony. Did you try to add it in your buildForm ?
Eg: ```$builder->add [..]
->add('save',Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType::class )```
Then, remove your Submit from the Twig template and replace it by ```{{ form_widget(form.save, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-default'} }) }}``` and that should do it.

Comment: Also, asking twice the same thing won't help a bit (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544593/symfony-form-submit-button-not-working).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony form submit button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544593/symfony-form-submit-button-not-working)

Comment: @NaeiKinDus yes I've already tried this, but then got the error that "methods" is not existing in my form layout. Even though I never used any variable called method. I'm pretty certain that it has something to do with my logic? 
and I asked it twice because I figured, that I didn't pose my question properly and thus tried to give other hints..

Comment: Should have edited your question then :)
Could you paste the exact error message in your question ? And the modified code too.
Adding ```{{ form_rest(form) }}``` for debugging purposes could help too.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus I updated my code and this is the error message:
Variable "method" does not exist. in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig at line 271

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155844/discussion-between-naeikindus-and-sonja).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several issues:

- you cannot add a submit button that is not bound to a Symfony form in your case because Symfony will not identify it properly (for lack of a name that has to match SF's automatic input names generation)

In your formBuilder put:

```
$builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

- your form has an incorrect name ("form") that conflicts with Twig's `form()` function, you have to change it,
- you might have an issue (not tested, just a guess) regarding the many calls made to Twig's `form()` because this function dumps the whole form content, to manually dump each part use

Your `{% block content %}` should have this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.your_widget_name, attrs) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved my issue:
1. as pointed out by @NaeiKinDus, I needed a Submit button that actually belonged to my form, plus I changed my form name to a custom **deactivationForm**

```
{% block content %}
{{ form(deactivationForm) }}
{% endblock content %}
```

the buildForm method:

```
    $builder
->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
  'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
  'choice_label' => 'name',
  'required' => false,
  'multiple' => true,
  'expanded' => false,
  'placeholder' => "Select Documents",
  'label' => 'label.document_list',
  'translation_domain' => 'Documents',
  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
      ->where('d.active = FALSE');
    },
))

->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
  'label' => 'Submit',
  'attr' => array(
      'class' => 'btn btn btn-default',
  ),
  ));
```

then in my controller:

```
/**
  * @Route("/document/bulkdeactivate", name="documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function bulkDeactivateAction(Request $request) {

    /*
      * GET DOCUMENT FROM DB
      */
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $selected_documents = $request->request->all();

      $deactivationForm = $this->createForm(DocumentDeactivationType::class);
      $deactivationForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($deactivationForm->isValid() && $deactivationForm->isSubmitted()) {
          foreach($selected_documents as $document) {
          $documentR = json_decode(json_encode($document), true);
          dump(count($documentR['documentlist']));
            for($i=0; $i<count($documentR['documentlist']); $i++){
              $doc = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($documentR['documentlist'][$i]);
              dump($documentR['documentlist'][$i]);
              $doc->setActive(true);
              $em->persist($doc);
              $em->flush();
            }
          }
          $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'The selected document(s) have been deactivated!'
          );
          return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
          }

        return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Panels:ActivationPanel.html.twig', array(
          'deactivationForm' => $deactivationForm->createView(),
        ));
}
```

I tried to access the wrong array positions (I didn't realize that the decoding of the ajax data sent me 3 array positions but I only wanted to access the first 'documentlist' and then get the document IDs from that one.